# Deleting temp file in a Spark datasource

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write a spark datasource package.

My datasource job is simple.

1. Get the content from remote system and store the content in a temp
   file
2. Construct dataframe using the content present in temp file

I was able to do the above stuff. But I want to delete the temp file once the dataframe has been constructed.

As Spark constructs the dataframe lazily, It can't be deleted from my DatasetRelation. So the option to delete from DefaultSource or DatasetRelation is ruled out.

Another option is add my temp folder in [ShutdownHookManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ShutdownHookManager.scala) which will take care of deleting my temp folder during spark shutdown. But unfortunately ShutdownHookManager is private.

Another option is get the temp directory that spark uses and deletes it during shutdown. There are temp directories created by spark. But I can't get the temp directory name created by spark. Spark creates temp directory with UUID in its directory name. Also there is no environment variable to get this temp directory. So not able to use this option as well.

Is there any other option to delete my temp file used to construct a dataframe in spark?

Comment: I don't know why it has been down voted. Please add comment if the question is not clear or missing anything? I didn't add my code as I thought it does not make sense. But if you thought otherwise I'll add it. But please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get the content from remote system and store the content in a temp file

You should probably not do this in spark. If you did it in an external script, you could pass the path to that script to spark and spark would then copy it to the cluster and delete it afterwards.